# Unresolved reference: launch

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Trying to run some examples for Kotlin coroutines, but can't build my project. I'm using the latest gradle release - 4.1

Any suggestions what to check/fix?

Here is `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'

kotlin {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    experimental {
        coroutines 'enable'
    }

    dependencies {
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.18"
    }
}
```

and the `main.kt`

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    launch (CommonPool) {
        delay(1000L)
        println("World!")
    }

    println("Hello, ")
    Thread.sleep(2000L)
}
```

when I run `gradle compileKotlin` I get the following

```
e: /Users/philippgrigoryev/projects/kotlin-coroutines/src/main/kotlin/main.kt: (2, 5): Unresolved reference: launch
e: /Users/philippgrigoryev/projects/kotlin-coroutines/src/main/kotlin/main.kt: (2, 13): Unresolved reference: CommonPool
e: /Users/philippgrigoryev/projects/kotlin-coroutines/src/main/kotlin/main.kt: (3, 9): Unresolved reference: delay`
```

Comment: Are you importing the `kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.*` package?

Comment: Doh! Of course you are right, I forgot to import the package! Thank you @nicholas.hauschild

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like already answered in the comments, the import is missing for the `kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.*` package. You can have a look at my examples at [GitHub](https://github.com/s1monw1/Kotlin_Examples/tree/master/src/main/kotlin/de/swirtz/kotlin/coroutines) if you like.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    launch(CommonPool) {
        delay(1000)
        LOG.debug("Hello from coroutine")
    }

}
```

Comment: what should I add to gradle to be able to import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.*?

Comment: it's an old answer. with new kotlin version, you should use GlobalScope.launch instead of launch

Answer (score 70):

Launch isn't used anymore directly. The [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html) suggests using:

```
fun main() { 
    GlobalScope.launch { // launch a new coroutine in background and continue
        delay(1000L)
        println("World!")
    }
    println("Hello,") // main thread continues here immediately
    runBlocking {     // but this expression blocks the main thread
        delay(2000L)  // ... while we delay for 2 seconds to keep JVM alive
    } 
}
```

Comment: Where does `GlobalScope` come from?

Comment: @hippietrail Looks like it's imported. It's declared as `public object GlobalScope : CoroutineScope` within the kotlinx-coroutines package.

Comment: launch, async are all functions of CoroutineScope class now, which can be accessed either through GlobalScope.launch, inside local scope by running things like coroutineScope { launch {} }, or create your own CoroutineScope

Answer (score 36):

If you are using Coroutines 1.0+, the import is no longer

> import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.*

but

> import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

You would need the following in the dependencies closure of your build.gradle (for Coroutines 1.0.1):

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.1'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1"
```

Comment: Hey, I'm still getting "Unresolved reference: launch", even though I imported the function. How is that even possible?

Comment: @alexey.hippie mb now they use different approach, there is no `launch` keyword anymore and you always need some `scope`, then you can use `scope.launch { ... }`: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/kotlin-coroutines/blob/19f36f6cdc6b90322b7eea00885e86f9c02bcaea/kotlin-coroutines-end/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/kotlincoroutines/main/MainViewModel.kt#L136

Comment: Thanks, @user25, that appeared to be issue. Worked with `GlobalScope.launch(...`

Comment: Unbelievably, in all the documentation and articles about coroutines, I could not find this complete information about how to import coroutines anywhere else.  Thank you.

Comment: This no longer works in 2019. See Christian's answer

Answer (score 4):

This confused me for a while because the tutorial I am doing shows it used directly... I think they have changed how it is used from a previous version.

I think the trick is that you can only call launch() within a Coroutine scope.

So this does not work:

```
fun main() {
    launch()  // not called within coroutine scope
}
```

Where this will work:

```
fun main() {
 runBlocking {
        launch()  // called within coroutine scope
    }
}
```

[code snippit example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GEeh.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try this way,

//add this lines to gradle

```
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$rootProject.kotlinx_coroutines"
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$rootProject.kotlinx_coroutines"


  class xyz{
     private val job = Job()
        private val coroutinesScope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(job + Dispatchers.IO)

      ....
     . ...
       coroutinesScope.launch {
                       // task to do
                        Timber.d("Delete Firebase Instance ID")
                    }


    // clear the job
      job.cancel()

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.1"
```

Instead of `launch`, `GlobalScope.launch` works.

Given below is the imports:-

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
```

Answer (score 1):

I met this issue while using kotlinx-corountine-core library, here is my gradle,

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.21'
    ext.kotlin_coroutines_version = '1.3.9'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.tencent.mm:AndResGuard-gradle-plugin:1.2.20'
    }
}

// .....

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar", '*.aar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlin_coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlin_coroutines_version"
}
```

Then the launch and many other references from kotlin coroutines can't be found. Here is my procedure to solve this problem,

First, find the final dependences under Android Studio. I'm surprised to find that the final kotlin coroutine library was 1.5.0, AND IT SHOULD BE EMPTY!

[image]

1.3.9 is also included, but 1.5.0 is greater. So, 1.5.0 will be used finally.

Then I tried to find out the project dependencies by the following command,

```
>gradlew :app:dependencies
```

where 'aap' is the project module name.

Then I found it's `lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx` using it.

So, I tried to upgrade the library to a greater version, 1.6.0. Then, I found it's not empty now and every references work again.

So, to solve it, you need,

1. find which version of kotlin coroutines core library you are using in your project
2. investigate what's going on in that library, is that 1.5.0 or empty?
3. find who introduced this version
4. try upgrade to a newer version

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CoroutineScope(coroutineContext).launch { 
        
    }
```

Comment: coroutineContext comes from?