# Android Studio errors in files but project compiles and run: Unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin

This poblem is solved.

The project compiles fine. However, Android studio 4.0.1 shows reference to one particular library in red and displays "Unresolved reference:launch".

I already tried various options like 1) Invalidate cache/restart 2) deleted build directory 3) clean and rebuild 4)4)delete .idea, .gradle but nothing seems to be working.
[This is the import code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMIPT.png)
[This is the code I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6RSw.png)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71'
    ext.navigation_version = '2.2.0-rc04'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigation_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}



apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin" //새로 추가

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += ["room.schemaLocation":
                                      "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    sourceSets {
        // Adds exported schema location as test app assets.
        androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    def room_version="2.3.0-alpha01"
    def nav_version = "2.2.0-rc04"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01'

    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc01"
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0-alpha01'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0' //annotationProcessor -> kapt

    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.3.0-alpha01"

    ...
}
```

Comment: this is Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46136136/unresolved-reference-launch

Comment: @Ganesh I don't think is duplicated, the link is about the project doesn't compile and the question is about project compiles but show unresolved references

Comment: @Chaeun Gong can you resolve this problem? How do you get work AS?

Comment: It is not duplicated. I just turned the computer off and on and it worked. I think it is just android studio's bug.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `Invalidate Caches/Restart` from the `File` menu solved the problem. No need to restart the computer.

Comment: No one answer helped. In my case helped to change coroutines version. From: 1.5.0 to 1.5.2

Answer (score 1):

In my case, moving the source code to another directory (or simply renaming the source folder) fixed the problem.
It's funny to note that the error comes back if I move it to the initial directory!